# navigating the dom javascript specific tag

Tags: javascript, dom

Here it is DOM structure:

```
<div id="some">
 <a href="#" style="color:red;">NOTHIS</a>
 <a href="#" style="color:red;">NOTHIS</a>
 <h3 class="myclass"><a href="#" style="color:red;">HELLO</a></h3>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of `HELLO` in javascript?

**EDIT:** Forgot, I have other anchor tags inside 'some', so I want strictly the anchor tag inside the h3's

**EDIT2:** Got it:

```
var n = document.getElementById('some').getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried the innerText property on the anchor tag?

Comment: @XSaint32 i think that property is IE-only.

Answer (score 5):

`var linkText = document.getElementById('some').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;`

or if you have jQuery

```
var linkText = $('#some').find('a').html();
```

Comment: hopefully he's not using bringing in an entire library specifically for this one thing though.

Comment: I don't think bringing in jquery, or at least sizzle, is a bad idea if you need to traverse the DOM only in a few places. DOM traversing with the DOM interface is always very brittle, any changes to the HTML will require a change to the code. Use getElementsByTagname if you don't mind brittle code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('some').getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
    yourText = anchor.innerText || anchor.textContent;
```

It's cross-browser, too. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Answer (score 0):

Propagate down the DOM from your ID.

```
var s = document.getElementById('some').getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
```

I would put an ID on the `a` myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var shouldEqualHello = document.getElementById('some').getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
```

edit: fixed

Comment: context.getElementsByTagName returns an array.

Comment: look at your selector with the 'h3'

Answer (score 0):

to get to a single dom element with javascript, you need a way to uniquely identify it. the ideal approach is to give your element a unique id.

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="#" style="color:red;">HELLO</a>
```

then you can directly obtain a reference in script.

```
var myAnchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
```

or if you are guaranteed that your element is the only anchor element within the "some" id you can do

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById('some');
var anchors = someDiv.getElementsByTagName('a'); // returns a list of anchor elements
var myAnchor = anchors[0]; // get the first element in the list
```

but since that's not the case you'll have to pick your way down through the dom some more.

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById('some');
var headers = someDiv.getElementsByTagName('h3');
var myH3 = headers[0];
var anchors = myH3 .getElementsByTagName('a'); // returns a list of anchor elements
var myAnchor = anchors[0]; // get the first element in the list
```

from there you can see the stuff between the tags with

```
alert(myAnchor.innerHTML);
```

or

```
alert(myAnchor.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

or some other method already mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use query selector,

```js
let result = document.querySelector('#some h3 a').innerText;
console.log(result);
```